# In K maps can a group be formed which consists only Don't Cares?

Tags: boolean, boolean-expression, reduction, karnaugh-map

While working with K maps,we can consider the don't cares as 0 or 1 whichever helps us to form a larger group.But can a group be made consisting of only don't cares????

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot form a group with just don't care terms. They are only used to make large groups consisting of 1s and 0s.